# filesystem::path constructor call fails

Tags: c++, boost

This code does not compile, using Boost 1.48 and GCC:

```
// const char* left, const char* right

boost::filesystem::path p =  boost::filesystem::absolute( 
   boost::filesystem::path(right, boost::filesystem::native),     // line 314
   boost::filesystem::path(left, boost::filesystem::native) );    // line 315
```

Error messages:

```
LoggerImplementation.cpp|314|error: invalid conversion from ‘bool (*)(const std::string&)’ to ‘void*’
LoggerImplementation.cpp|314|error:   initializing argument 2 of ‘boost::filesystem3::path::path(const Source&, typename boost::enable_if<boost::filesystem3::path_traits::is_pathable<typename boost::decay<Source>::type>, void>::type*) [with Source = const char*]’
LoggerImplementation.cpp|315|error: invalid conversion from ‘bool (*)(const std::string&)’ to ‘void*’
LoggerImplementation.cpp|315|error:   initializing argument 2 of ‘boost::filesystem3::path::path(const Source&, typename boost::enable_if<boost::filesystem3::path_traits::is_pathable<typename boost::decay<Source>::type>, void>::type*) [with Source = const char*]’
```

Under MSVC it compiles. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second argument (`boost::filesystem::native`) is wrong. `boost::filesystem::path` simply [doesn’t have a constructor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#path-constructors) which takes this argument – leave it off and the code compiles.

In fact, `boost::filesystem::native` is a *function*, and using it in the manner you tried makes no sense. Furthermore, if MSVC compiles this code, that’s a definitive bug (it is using an implicit conversion from a function pointer to `void*`, which doesn’t exist according to the standard).